# $\sum_1^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln{(2\cosh{n})}}}$ convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I test this serie for convergence ? Logarithmic criterion didnt seem to work.
How to test if it converges absolutely ? As Leibnitz works
$$\sum_1^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln{(2\cosh{n})}}}$$

Comment: Alternating series test. $\frac{1}{\ln{(2\cosh{n})}}$ is eventually monotone decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint:** alternating series test is your tool.

Comment: Yes but for absolute ?

Comment: For absolute test try to compare with the series $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n \to 0$ monotonically, then $\sum_1^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ converges. This is called the alternating series test. Show that it works here.